# C# Form inheritance and transfer of data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 different `Forms`. My first form `Form1` is the main form that has a `TextBox` called `textbox1`. My other form is called `FontSettings` and is supposed to be used so `Form1` can inherit `FontSettings` data. I am trying to send a `string` and `2 integers` from `FontSettings` to `Form1`. It looks like this.

- **FontSettings**:

  ```
  Form1 form1 = new Form1();
  form1.insertFont(family, size, color);
  ```
- **Form1**:

  ```
  public void insertFont(string a, int b, string c)
  {
      if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
      {
          xx = textBox1.SelectedText;
          textBox1.SelectedText = textBox1.SelectedText.Replace(xx, "" + a + "\" + b + c + "a");    
      }
      else
      {
          textBox1.Paste("" + a + "\" + b + c + "a");
      }
  }
  ```

The string and both integers used, are **public**.

Someone please describe to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which form is current? By the sounds of your description 'form1' is the startup form of your application?

Comment: Form1 is the startup but fontsettings is a pop up window that you need to select comboboxes to get the Strings/ints and click a button to start the code you see

Answer (score 0):

Simples. See the below code which opens FontSettings form from 'form1'

```
FontSettings newform = new FontSettings();
newform.ShowDialog();
MessageBox.Show(newform.MyString);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", newform.MyInt1));
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", newform.MyInt2));
```

Then in the FontSettings form, create some public properties so they can be referenced from 'form1'

```
public string MyString { get; set; }
public int MyInt1 { get; set; }
public int MyInt2 { get; set; }
```

Then in a button click do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyString = "some value here...";
    MyInt1 = 28;
    MyInt2 = 77;
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify form1 property from forsettings, one way to do it is find the form1 contrls and modify it directly as below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["textBox1"] as TextBox;
    t.Text = "some value here...";
    // do the same for the other two controls
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description,it sounds like you are making a text editor kind of application like Notepad.Well, if this is the case then its a lot easier to use three static fields.The code below will make this clear.

> To proceed define three static fields in Form1 class,like this;

```
public static string family="";
public static int size=0;
public static string color="";
```

I guess you have three TextBoxes' and a `Close Button` on class `FontSettings`,if this is so,then add the code below to `Click Event` of Button;

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFamily.Text))//Check if textBoxFamily is not empty.
    {
        Form1.family = textBoxFamily.Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSize.Text))//Check if textBoxSize is not empty.
        {
            Form1.size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxColor.Text))//Check if textBoxColor is not empty.
            {
                Form1.color = textBoxColor.Text;

                this.Close();//If everything happens correctly,close FontSettings.
            }
        }
    }
```

Now as we have declared the fields in `Form1`,we can use their values directly,like this;

```
public void insertFont()
{
    if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        xx = textBox1.SelectedText;
        textBox1.SelectedText = textBox1.SelectedText.Replace(xx, "" + family + "\" + size + color + "a");    
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Paste("" + family + "\" + size + color + "a");
    }
}
```

Hope it's enough to get you back on track.If there's anything left,please inform me.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tweaked my code because they are comboboxes but it still doesn't paste anything. It does close after it completes but nothing gets pasted.